# IBM serveraid problems

Tags: raid, ibm

When I start my server serveraid gives me this error: not responding properly Error 00D0
any help would be appreciated.

I can't find any information on this. Where can I go to get more information on this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Raise the logging level of your server in order to find the cause in some logfiles. [Here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/eserver/v1r2/index.jsp?topic=/diricinfo/fqy0_aagntel_copy.html) you have some documentation on the logfiles in ServeRAID. There seem to be lots of documentation on this product.

There's also a section on [troubleshooting IBM ServeRAID](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/director/v5r2/index.jsp?topic=/serveraid_5.20/fqy0_main.html.). This might be helpful as well.

If you're still unable to resolve this issue on your own, I'd suggest you open a ticket with IBM themselves since you're not providing detailed information on the error.